# Enqueing a jQuery script in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue a jQuery script to my Wordpress site but for some reason it is not adding. Below is my code I've added to my child theme's functions.php file.

```
<?php

function itm_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', '/wp-content/themes/italic-child/js/jQuery.equalHeights.js/js/jQuery.equalHeights.js',   array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( '_enqueue_scripts', 'itm_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `action` missing `wp` prefix

Change

```
add_action( '_enqueue_scripts', 'itm_adding_scripts' );
```

To

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'itm_adding_scripts' );
```

Reference:  [wp_enqueue_scripts docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your action. It should be **wp_enqueue_scripts**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'itm_adding_scripts' );
```